# System.out.println(16 >>> 3)?

Tags: java, jvm

I try the code

`System.out.println( 16 >>> 3);`

and the output is 2 !

but how does this work? What is the syntax?

Comment: This summarizes bit shifting pretty well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Dividing by 2 for three times. But only exct division for multiples of 8;

Comment: Not sure I understand all the up-votes. No indication of research in my opinion. Down-vote from me.

Comment: @delnan Not convinced that's a duplicate. It simply appears to be another question about the `>>>` operator.

Comment: @Duncan, its the "and the output is 2!" It just tickled me. Maybe I need more sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another note, the 3 chevrons indicate an **unsigned** right bit shift. Although it does not make a difference in this example...

The extra `>` indicates the sign is not reserved, an example:

```
-128 >> 2 = -128 / 2^2 = -32
```

The signed bit is retained giving:

```
(1) 10000000 >> 2 = (1) 100000 
11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000 >> 2 = 1111111 11111111 11111111 11100000
```

If `>>>` is used then the signed bit is also shifted converting it to a positive number.

```
-128 >>> 2 = 536870896

11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000 >> 2 = 0011111 11111111 11111111 11100000
```

Comment: Id be interested to see examples of where it would make a difference, would negative numbers be multipiled by 2?

Comment: Try to Google it, there are already plenty of examples on the web, and even SO. But basically no, negative numbers are not multiplied by 2. The signed bit is not reserved, so they become some positive value. For example consider the signed (32bit) integer -128: 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000. If we perform (-128 >>> 3) you get 536870896. Because the signed bit is shifted to give 00011111 11111111 11111111 11110000

Comment: Fair enough, I was more implying that would make your answer awesome and I would upvote it but fair enough I'll move along

Comment: I guess it wouldn't really answer your question at the top though :p

Comment: My question? Im not Rafael

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry! Ill update my answer anyway after all these comments

Answer (score 8):

16 >> 3 is a bitshift to the right, and is equivalent to dividing by 8 (2 ** 3).

```
16 -> 00010000
         ^
          \
           \
2 ->  00000010
```

Answer (score 3):

This is called *right-shift* with *zero-fill* (also called - *unsigned right shift*).

To make it easy to understand, for every shift, your number is divided by 2. So:

```
16 >>> 3  ==  16 / 2^3 == 16 / 8 == 2
```

For more details see, [JLS - Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).

For real visualization, take a look at the bit representation of the two numbers:

```
16        - 00010000
16 >>> 3  - 00000010 == 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The `>>>` operator is performing an unsigned right-shift of bits, when applied to an integer it has the effect of dividing by two. In particular, if the integer is a power of two, each right-shift exactly halves the value. For example:

```
16 >>> 1 // returns 8
16 >>> 2 // returns 4
16 >>> 3 // returns 2
```

In binary form, `16` is represented as `10000`. If we shift the value three times to the right it ends up as `00010`, which is `2`. Also, take a look at the Java [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're using a bitwise shift consult  [this post](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

In binary, every 0 is an increasing magnitude of the power 2 for example:

10000 = 16

01000 = 8

00100 = 4

00010 = 2

00001 = 1

The expression 16 >>> 3 in java is saying to move the bit over 3 places, so we are left with 2.

Answer (score 0):

16 in binary is `00010000`. You are shifting the bits right three positions which results in `00000010` which is 2

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit shift, which is dividing by 2^3 (due to shifting by 3 positions) and truncating(rounding down) as we are not doing fillaround.

When using `>>>` we move to the right and divide.
When using `<<<` it goes opposite, so you'd multiply by the correct power of 2.

Bit shifts are a type of [bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) that operates on a primitive(almost always number's) bits directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's an *unsigned right shift operator*, and the above shifts *3* times.

i.e. it divides by 2 each time, giving you *2*.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for more information on Java operators.